# MacBook Pro battery will not charge even though cycle count is below max count

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery, power, magsafe

I haven't used my MacBook Pro (Mid 2011 version with non-removable battery) for over 6 months, as I was out of country. Now it only works on power connected and battery won't change.

Symptoms I observed:

1. The Battery Status is: Replace Now.
2. MagSafe gives green light.
3. Battery indicator: All LEDs flash 5 times.
4. Coconut battery software shows 0 mAh though the MagSafe is connected.
5. Coconut battery software also shows load cycles as 564, which is not max and I feel there is still life in it.
6. The Battery state is: Discharging

I ran a AHT diagnostic and it shows 4xxx/1/40000000 Battery Issue
I did disconnect and connect of Battery as some youtube video's suggested, it didn't work either.

Is the Battery really dead or any logic board issues might be there?

I am thinking to replace with new battery myself manually. Need suggestions on that.

Comment: What's with the title?

Comment: I am not good with english or may be bad in asking questions :p

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your battery is dead or there may be an issue with a component in the charging system. Only a trip to Apple will resolve this.

I had a similar issue with my similar MacBook Pro. The battery showed bad, and it would only run when plugged in. It turned out to be a problem with the charge indicator unit (the thing that shows 5 tiny lights). It had a bad chip, and it was not allowing the battery to charge. A quick swap of the part and my Macbook Pro was back to normal, showing a full battery.

Send to Apple or go to the Apple store, as these kinds of things often show in very strange ways.

Answer (score 0):

Your battery is dead because of 6 months without exercise.
Check it if you want to be sure at an Apple Store.
If I was wrong, please bring back their analysis and kill my answer :).